# Failed when using _vscwprintf to handle utf-8 encoded string on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

```
static std::wstring format_string(CONST WCHAR* pszText, ...)
{
    std::wstring result;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, pszText);
    int len = _vscwprintf(pszText, args);
    if (len < 0)
    {
        wprintf_s(L"_vscwprintf failed, len=%i, error=%i\n", len, errno);
        return L"";
    }
    result.resize((size_t)len);
    vswprintf_s(const_cast<WCHAR*>(result.data()), result.size() + sizeof(WCHAR), 
                pszText, args);
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    wprintf_s(L"%S\n", setlocale(LC_ALL, ".UTF8"));
    std::wstring msg = format_string(L"msg: %S", u8"abc你好");
    wprintf_s(L"msg: %s\n", msg.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Chinese (Simplified)_China.utf8
_vsctprintf failed, len=-1, error=0
msg:
```

Env:

```
OS: Windows 10
Compiler: vs2019, mingw-w64-v8.1.0
Project Charset：UNICODE
```

Why _vsctprintf failed, how to fix it?
Is there any way to use _vsctprintf to handle utf-8 utf-8 encoded strings?
Hope someone can help me.
Thank you!

Complete project file: [test_utf8.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jGPvPBuB5hcnksuH90g1l9b277WA-SDF/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Did you define _UNICODE and UNICODE?
Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vscprintf-vscprintf-l-vscwprintf-vscwprintf-l?view=msvc-160. _vsctprintf maps to either _vscprintf or _vscwprintf depending on those defines.

Comment: Yes, it's defined by visual studio, like this:  /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE"

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong specifier here:

```
std::wstring msg = format_msg(L"msg: %S", u8"abc你好");
```

Instead of `%S`, you want `%s`.
From MSDN docs:

For `%s` specifier:

> When used with printf functions, specifies a single-byte or multi-byte
> character string; when used with wprintf functions, specifies a
> wide-character string. Characters are displayed up to the first null
> character or until the precision value is reached.

For `%S` specifier:

> When used with printf functions, specifies a wide-character string;
> when used with wprintf functions, specifies a single-byte or
> multi-byte character string. Characters are displayed up to the first
> null character or until the precision value is reached.

Since your application is unicode, `%s` specifies a wide-character string.

On a side note, you should not use the generic "t" versions of string functions (`_vsctprintf`, `_tcsstr` etc.) from `tchar.h` in conjunction with non "t" versions (`_vscprintf`, `_vscwprintf`, `strstr`, `wcsstr` etc.). That can easily break stuff when switching between unicode and non-unicode.

Comment: %s doesn't work, may trigger warning C4477. %hs or %S works for wprintf_s(L"%hs\n", u8"abc你好") fine, but not work for  _vscwprintf, will return -1.

Comment: What is the exact command and warning? I have tested this with the exact options you gave in your comment with VS2019 tools.

Comment: %s will cause incorrect output, you can try this: [test_utf8.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jGPvPBuB5hcnksuH90g1l9b277WA-SDF/view?usp=sharing)